# MySQL: настройка репликации на локальном хосте

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, репликация

Хочу настроить репликацию баз данных на mysql, на одном не получается, не могу запустить  подчинённый сервер. Все делаю по инструкции этого [видео на phpmyadmin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfsmnx24gxU) при попытке запуска подчиненного сервера phpmyadmin виснет безнадежно.... Поэтому хочу создать два сервака и попробовать [вручную](http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+MySQL+Master-Slave+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E).

Comment: На сколько мне известно, создать 2 сервера на одной ОСь не возможно. В документации по ссылке показано создание серверов на локальном компе с виртуальной системой и использующий 2 Сетевые карты/VLAN если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: @Insider [Документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-servers.html) на MySQL  с Вами не согласна: "It is possible to use a different MySQL server binary per instance, or use the same binary for multiple instances, or any combination of the two approaches."

Comment: @Insider это физически невозможно. Можно это очень сильно затруднить, но намертво запретить поднять два процесса - это невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве одного из варианта можно попробовать запустить репликацию на одном и том же IP-адресе и на двух разных портах, например, 3306 и 3307. Для этого у MySQL-сервера существует специальная директива port, которую можно указать либо в конфигурационном файле my.cnf в разделе [mysqld]

```
[mysqld]
...
port = 3307
```

либо указав в параметре `--port` при старте сервера.

```
mysqld --port=3307
```

Если master-серверу достанется нестандартный порт 3307, в этом случае, вам придется явно указать его в операторе `CHANGE MASTER TO`.

PS Сервера лучше настроить вручную не прибегая к phpMyAdmin, дело в том, что репликация шутка довольно хрупкая и может быть нарушена. Для ее восстановления потребуется навык работы в командной строке, чем быстрее найбьете руку и разберетесь в базовых командах - тем вам проще будет поддерживать ее в эксплуатации.